# error "No module named MySQLdb"

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

After importing the module, on script run I get the error and I have the module installed already, I am new with python, so I expect I might have forgot to install something else? Python is version 2.7.

Comment: Have you installed the module?? does it come with your python distribution??

Comment: i used sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
and get 
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have more versions than 2.7 and You installed the module on another version.